# JSF (2.2) ViewScope using Spring 4.3.7 on Weblogic 12.2.1.2 with JDK 8 (on Mac OS and Docker Oracle Linux enviroment)

Tags: java, spring, jsf, weblogic, weblogic12c

I try to configure Spring 4.3.7 integration with JSF 2.2.14 and Primefaces 6.0. Spring should be responsible for managing scope and ManagedBean from JSF became Spring's beans.

I have configured Weblogic 12.2.1.2 on Mac OS and on Docker with Oracle Linux.

I read and tested this solution (http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-jsf-2-integration-example-using-autowired-annotation) but didn't work. I found this one (https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes/) that prevent memory leaks problems but didn't work too.

I could perceive independent of scope (session or view) Spring is working like a request bean.

My configurations and a bean sample. When I access navigation *.xhtml. Independent if I configure Scope as view or session, the method defined on PostConstruct is called any times and pagination didn't work because the state of view is not persisted. I don't know what could cause this behavior.

**WebConfig Spring:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "packageC" },basePackageClasses {PackageA.class,PackageB.class})
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class WebAppConfig{

@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
    log.info("create customScopeConfigurer bean");
Map<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<>();
    scopes.put("view", new CustomViewScope());

    CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    customScopeConfigurer.setScopes(scopes);
    return customScopeConfigurer;
}
}
```

**Faces-config.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
  version="2.2">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>

</application>

 <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>packagetest.listener.PhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

**WebAppInitializer:**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    log.info("call WebAppInitializer.onStartup");
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ServiceConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    log.info("end call WebAppInitializer.onStartup");
}
}
```

**JSF Bean sample:**

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("accountBean")
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class AccountManagedBeanImpl extends GenericManagedBeanAb<AccountEntity, Long> implements AccountManagedBean {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4359183101897060165L;

@Autowired
AccountService accountService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {    
    log.info("init do bean: AccountManagedBeanImpl. Escopo = session");
    this.entity = new AccountEntity();
    if (getRequest().getParameter("codigo") != null) {
        Optional op = accountService.findByPrimaryKey(Long.parseLong(getRequest().getParameter("codigo")));
        if (op.isPresent()) {
            this.entity = (AccountEntity) op.get();
        }
    }
    this.entityFilter = new AccountEntity();
    this.listEntitySelected = new ArrayList<AccountEntity>(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the same application on Wildfly 9.x and it works. I could conclude CDI on Weblogic has a different behavior and it isn't delegating the context to SPRING DI.

I wouldn't like to use EJB, I prefer to use Spring Service Layer integrating with Spring Data + Spring AOP...

I'm still looking for a solution, but this information can be useful for someone